# ElectronNet/Electron.NET Error installing extension

Tags: node.js, electron, electron.net

I am getting error when trying to install extension using ElectronNet.
The code I'm trying to install the extension.

```js
var browserExtensionWindow = await Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync(new BrowserWindowOptions()
            {
                Width = 360,
                Height = 520,
                Type = "popup",
                DarkTheme = true,
                Show = false,
                AutoHideMenuBar = true,
                Maximizable = false,
                Resizable = false
            });
            Session session = browserExtensionWindow.WebContents.Session;
            await session.LoadExtensionAsync("extension-path", true);
```

Error:

> (node:26580) ExtensionLoadWarning: Warnings loading extension at
> AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
> Data\Default\Extensions\nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn\10.8.1_0:
> Unrecognized manifest key 'author'.   Unrecognized manifest key
> 'browser_action'.   Unrecognized manifest key 'chrome_url_overrides'.
> Unrecognized manifest key 'commands'.   Unrecognized manifest key
> 'minimum_chrome_version'.   Unrecognized manifest key 'short_name'.
> Unrecognized manifest key 'update_url'.   Manifest contains a
> differential_fingerprint key that will be overridden on extension
> update.   Permission 'activeTab' is unknown or URL pattern is
> malformed.   Permission 'notifications' is unknown or URL pattern is
> malformed.   Cannot load extension with file or directory name
> *metadata. Filenames starting with "*" are reserved for use by the system.

At first I thought it couldn't load the manifest.json file. But according to the error, the manifest is loading.